# Autogenerate HTML files out emacs help

Tags: documentation

Am I right to say that the content I read when doing `C-h f foobar` (or something like that) is read directly from the lisp sources? In Python I would call it docstrings.

In Python I can use Sphinx, doxygen, etc. to create HTML (or other formats) out of those in-source-doc-strings.

Is there something like this I can use for lisp code?

Comment: I am not aware of an existing package that provides something like this. However, I think a very/the most useful answer to this question is provided at [the blog of the Kitchin research group](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/10/17/Generate-emacs-lisp-documentation/) (of course you could export the org file to html instead of pdf). If you are ambitious, I think you could contribute a package for this (possibly acknowledging J. Kitchin).

Comment: J Kitchin already posted his org source file, which provides a great start!

Comment: I've never heard of such a utility, but a plugin to Sphinx or doxygen for this would be sweet. I wouldn't be surprised if there was a function or two buried in one of the older, larger packages like Org Mode or CEDET that "exported" "docstrings" to various formats. Of course it might be faster to write your own than sleuth it out.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot about it (yes i can). Not automatic, but might get you on your way. https://github.com/hniksic/emacs-htmlize also listed under https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SaveAsHtml